# GCM string instead of boolean

Tags: java, android, json, boolean, google-cloud-messaging

I've received message from GCM but i got string instead of boolean. It seems problem is with my JSON array. I get warning message:

```
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702): Key alarm expected Boolean but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value false was returned.
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(Bundle.java:786)
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at android.content.Intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.java:3282)
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at com.rolandas.lookup.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:71)
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-17 00:41:04.058: W/Bundle(6702):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

PHP send script.

```
   $devices = array();
   $data = array();
   array_push($devices, getRegId($user_id, $mysqli));
   $data = array("alarm" => true);

   SendGCM(true, $devices, $data);
```

JSON message:

```
{"registration_ids":["APA91bFjtwqq2q5Ji88JjLjuivAzNVGxLDYXaIahCeRUOmaD6vb0T5C22uQSlygztpq_KsVGCZ-0TKQTqUsmp0PU4FXjKYfdsfsdfaxRM1gQ7oh5xHf576-JwQ9FuItsBvhQeQmiKoX3UIi0s3onBh9vO7wI3_Pvw"],"data":{"alarm":true}}
```

And finally my OnMessage method:

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean alarm = false;

        alarm = intent.getBooleanExtra("alarm", false);


    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By the time the message gets to you, it is a String, quoting from [Google's online docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) under the **Sending Messages, request format** 'data' section:

> The values could be any JSON object, but we recommend using strings,
>   since the values will be converted to strings in the GCM server
>   anyway. If you want to include objects or other non-string data types
>   (such as integers or booleans), you have to do the conversion to
>   string yourself.